# I have some points in 3D and I want to find interpolating linear function by Mathematica

Tags: plotting, fitting

This is the code that I use:

```
data = {{313, 0.0548, 64.8770}, {333, 0.0530, 62.4863},
        {353, 0.0520, 60.4954}, {373, 0.0498, 58.6643},
        {393, 0.0482, 56.3851}, {413, 0.0466, 54.1374},
        {433, 0.0436, 51.8590}, {443, 0.0426, 49.2803}};

ListPointPlot3D[
 data
 , PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and there are 8 points.

**I am looking for a *Mathematica* command to find the interpolating linear function that is the nearest to these points.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your points don't look coplanar, so interpolation is out of the question. You can fit a line or plane to your points, tho.

Comment: I appreciate for your answers. Yes my goal was to fit a line in 3D space. Thank you. Helped a lot.

Comment: Last question. Can I obtain this linear equation directly or what is this linear equation?

Comment: @MehmetSenol Please don't use answers for comments. And this is not a discussion pannel. Separate issue = separate topic, unless it is quick follow up question, then you can as in comments for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`LinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html) for fitting `y` and `z` independently.

```
data = {{313, 0.0548, 64.8770}, {333, 0.0530, 62.4863},
        {353, 0.0520, 60.4954}, {373, 0.0498, 58.6643},
        {393, 0.0482, 56.3851}, {413, 0.0466, 54.1374},
        {433, 0.0436, 51.8590}, {443, 0.0426, 49.2803}};

lmfxz = LinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 3}]], x, x];

lmfxy = LinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 2}]], x, x];
```

Now your function is

```
{x, lmfxy[x], lmfxz[x]}
(* {x, 0.0843133 - 0.0000929621 x, 100.575 - 0.113429 x} *)
```

And the coefficients have estimation errors given by

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the ranges for `{x,y,z}`

```
MinMax /@ Transpose[data]
(* {{313, 443}, {0.0426, 0.0548}, {49.2803, 64.877}} *)
```

Now we plot your points and the two  [`FittedModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FittedModel.html)  using  [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[
  data
  , PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]
  ],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {x, lmfxy[x], lmfxz[x]}
  , {x, 313, 443}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I think your goal is to fit a line in 3D space ,the least squares method for curve fitting is used to get the equation.

look at this：http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html

```
data = {{313, 0.0548, 64.8770}, {333, 0.0530, 62.4863}, {353, 0.0520, 
    60.4954}, {373, 0.0498, 58.6643}, {393, 0.0482, 56.3851}, {413, 
    0.0466, 54.1374}, {433, 0.0436, 51.8590}, {443, 0.0426, 49.2803}};
vx[i_] = {x@i, y@i, z@i};
d = Norm[Cross[vx@0 - vx@1, vx@0 - vx@2]]/Norm[vx@2 - vx@1] // 
   Simplify;
fit = FindFit[{##, 0} & @@@ data, d, vx@1~Join~vx@2, vx@0, 
   Method -> NMinimize];
model = {t*(x[2] - x[1]) + x[1], t*(y[2] - y[1]) + y[1], 
   t*(z[2] - z[1]) + z[1]};
modelf = Function[{t}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]

Show[ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
     ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[model /. fit], {t, 1.9, 3}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

or

```
mat = ArrayPad[data, {{0}, {0, 1}}, 1];
{{m, x0}, {n, y0}} = Transpose[
   mat[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]].mat[[;; ,3 ;; 4]].Inverse[(Transpose[
      mat[[;; , 3 ;; 4]]].mat[[;; , 3 ;; 4]])]
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[data], 
  InfiniteLine[{x, y, z} /. 
    FindInstance[x == x0 + m z && y == y0 + n z, {x, y, z}, Reals, 
     2]]}]
```